# Simple verification with code

Tags: c++, authentication

I've been trying to find a solution that seems like it may be more difficult that I originally though. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
Program 1:
Generates an ID code...
ID: 1234567


Program 2:
Takes that code and generates an unlock code:
Input > Enter ID: 1234567
Output > Unlock Code: 987654

Back to Program 1:
ID: 1234567
Enter Unlock Code: 987654
Code accepted, now doing other stuff...
```

I've only been able to find info on generating product license keys that are too complicated or encrypting data. I'm just trying to find a simple solution and can't even find one example of what I'm trying to create anywhere so I'm not sure what to call it to search online.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting and decrypting may be a good solution, but if you are looking for something different, you can use a random number generator and store lock and unlock codes in `std::map`. Then you can easily use those pairs.

For random number generation, Combined MRG from [L'Ecuyer (1999)](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/papers.html) is a good algorithm. It also has a `c` library that you can possibly easily integrate.

- [mrand.c](https://code.google.com/p/avc2011repo/source/browse/trunk/source/planner/mrand.c?r=161)
- [mrand_seeds.h](https://code.google.com/p/avc2011repo/source/browse/trunk/source/planner/mrand_seeds.h?r=161)